# Reportlab bold and normal text in one paragraph

Tags: python, formatting, reportlab

I'm creating a PDF using reportlab (in conjunction with Django). I have created the following code for creating a table with heads and details:

```
elements = []
datas = []
course_info = [
               ['Course Code' , c.course_code] ,
               ['Course Title' , c.course_name],
               ['Prerequisites by Course(s) and Topics', c.pre_reqs],
               ['Assessment Instruments with Weights (some desc)', c.grade_distribution]
            ]

for k in course_info: 
    headpara = Paragraph(k[0], styleB)

    datas.append([headpara , Paragraph(clean_string(k[1]), styleN)])

t = LongTable(datas, colWidths=[5 * cm, 12 * cm])

t.setStyle(TableStyle(org.getTableStyle()))
elements.append(t)
doc.build(elements)
```

I'm using BaseDocTemplate as my template. **What I want is to be able to give parts of the `headpara` as non-bold e.g. the `(some desc)` part in the fourth row need to be normal style instead of bold.** How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reportlab supports simple HTML formatting so we can use `styleN` and make the required text bold. Like so:

```
course_info = [
               ['<b>Course Code</b>' , c.course_code] ,
               ['<b>Course Title</b>' , c.course_name],
               ['<b>Prerequisites by Course(s) and Topics</b>', c.pre_reqs],
               ['<b>Assessment Instruments with Weights</b> (some desc)', c.grade_distribution]
            ]

for k in course_info: 
    headpara = Paragraph(k[0], styleN) 
    datas.append([headpara , Paragraph(clean_string(k[1]), styleN)])
```